# java.io.File.exists() fails on Windows 7

Tags: java, file, windows-7

This is crazy.  A java program is failing in the simplest way imaginable.  It looks for its configuration file located in `${user.home}` from System properties.  I log where the program is looking for the file, and have verified that the file it is looking for does in fact exist and that it's in the right place.  But when the program runs, it fails to find the configuration file (checking first with `File.exists()).  This is on a PC running Windows 7.  The same program runs without this happening on a number of other PCs running either Windows 7 or XP.

At first, I thought the fact that I was running this program using Remote Desktop Connection from an XP box could possibly be significant.  There are some Google hits pertaining to this on .NET `file.exists()`.  However, when my colleague goes directly to the PC in question and attempts to run the program locally, the same thing happens.

I am stumped.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
static private File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File configFile = new File(configDir, fileName);
log.debug("config file directory is " + configDir);
if (configFile.exists()) {
...
} else {
   log.info("Override Configuration from File System not found.");
}
```

Comment: My first intuition is that you have file permission issues. What permissions are on the file and what rights does the program have while running?

Comment: Just a dumb idea: have you checked under which user was program running (and if the settings file was *there*)? The first thing I noticed about 7 is that home directories had a slightly different location.

Comment: File permissions on Windows 7?  We are logged in as the user, in the User's own home directory.  I don't think that could be it.  I know about the different file location of home directory under 7 and have taken that into account.  The log statements tell me that I have the right home directory and am looking in the right place.

Comment: Yes, file permissions on Windows 7. :) Have you not heard of UAC? Even administrators have restricted rights on Windows 7; non-admin users have severely restricted rights. Where *exactly* is `configDir` looking?  (You posted everything except the specific path.)

Comment: configDir is C:\Users\{id of logged in user}

Comment: On Win7, there are several levels of folder under `C:\Users\<userid>`, many of which are not accessible even by that user. Look at the hidden `AppData` folder, for instance, and the `Local`, `LocalLow`, and `Roaming` folders beneath it. You should check MSDN for info on [SHGetFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762180(v=vs.85).aspx) (deprecated for Vista and above - see the links for Vista/Win7 preferred function) for actual folder locations and uses.

Comment: Oh, geez!  You mean to say that new File( System.getProperty("user.home")) returns a file that user himself doesn't have access to?

Comment: Still not understanding this.  This file is not in some hidden directory BELOW C:\Users\<userid>, it's IN C:\Users\<userid> itself.  The file can be seen in Windows Explorer and opened in Notepad, so the system does not have a problem dealing with the file or the directory.  As far as I know, only java.io.File.exists() has a problem seeing it.  This is with jre1.6.0_26, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem while coding an interview solution and it turned out to be due to the fact that the file was actually called

`foo.txt.txt`

but showed up as:

`foo.txt`.

I have a strong suspicion that either this is or the permissions issue mentioned in the comments above is causing this issue.  But if you can open the file as the same user that the Java program executes as, then you can rule out the permissions issue.  In Windows you can click a checkbox that shows the file extensions.  Here's a [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions) that demonstrates how to toggle this behaviour.